# How to override the Gnome 3 SSH handler?

Tags: gnome3, gvfs

I would like to be able to click on SSH links that look like `ssh://user@servername` and have a gnome-terminal open that runs SSH inside of it.

After reading up on the XDG stuff I did the following:

I created a shell script in $HOME/bin/ssh-terminal with the following:

```
#!/bin/sh
dest=${1#ssh://}
gnome-terminal -e "ssh $dest" &
```

This works from the command line.

I created $HOME/.local/share/applications/ssh-terminal.desktop with:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Type=Application
Name=SSH Terminal
Exec=ssh-terminal %u
Icon=utilities-terminal
StartupNotify=false
MimeType=x-scheme-handler/ssh;
```

I ran `update-desktop-database ~/.local/share/applications/`

Now when I try to run `xdg-open ssh://user@hostname` I get the following error:

```
$ xdg-open ssh://buildbot@10.16.50.74
gvfs-open: sftp://buildbot@10.16.50.74/: error opening location: The specified location is not mounted
```

I don't *want* to open it as a sftp mount and I cannot seem to find where that is set!

Where do I go from here?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Writing a `.desktop` file is not enough. You also need to change the default setting for the mime type.

You can get the current default value with

```
 xdg-mime query default x-scheme-handler/ssh
```

and can change it with

```
 xdg-mime default ssh-terminal.desktop x-scheme-handler/ssh
```

The corresponding configuration file could be `$HOME/.config/mimeapps.list` or  `$HOME/.local/share/applications/mimeapps.list` depending on your OS version.

Comment: Sorry about the late accept. This didn't work at the time I asked the question but I just tried it lately and it does now. Thanks.

Comment: To keep this excellent answer temporally relevant, in Ubuntu 18.04 LTS, the corresponding configuration file is now in `$HOME/.config/mimeapps.list`.  At least for me, the one listed here in `~/.local/share/applications` is 0 bytes.

Comment: @MichaelCampbell thanks, I updated the answer.

Answer (score 1):

None of this worked for me until I edited the following file and removed the `SchemeAlias` line on `/usr/share/gvfs/mounts/sftp.mount`

```
[Mount]
Type=sftp
Exec=/usr/lib/gvfs/gvfsd-sftp
AutoMount=false
Scheme=sftp
# SchemeAliases=ssh
DefaultPort=22
HostnameIsInetAddress=true
```

Comment: For anyone who encounters this (I did), you have to restart Gnome/Unity/Cinnamon for this to take effect. If you don't know how, restarting your computer should do the trick.