# How to automatically start an ssh session when clicking on ssh:// URIs?

Tags: ssh, url

URI like `https://`, `ftp://`, even game specific `ut2004://` or `tel://` starts the default program associated with the protocol when clicking on links, but most linux distributions default configuration do not react to clicking on `ssh://` URIs, how one could configure in a XDG desktop compliant way the possibility to automatically open the default terminal and start ssh with the parameters within the URI ?

Comment: The link handling is application specific - in what context (browser, terminal, text editor ?) are you clicking on the url?

Comment: Browser, keepass, hexchat, signal. I'm expecting to be able to just click an URL when the  software recognize it is one and already made it clicable. The issue I try to resolve is there are no configured handlers, I doubt each of these software took the time to specifically support a year 2004 game.

Comment: Then each application needs specific fixing.

Comment: After further search, this may be the solution. I would need to create the "x-scheme-handler/ssh" handler myself. https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/55214/how-to-override-the-gnome-3-ssh-handler … will test